# Are there any photos or videos of the drones at Gatwick?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, closed-runways

The Gatwick Airport drone incident from 19-21 December 2018 involved "67 reports of drone sightings close to the runway" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatwick_Airport_drone_incident)).

However, police stated there were no photos or videos of the drone ([The Guardian, 23 Dec.](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/dec/23/gatwick-drone-chaos-arrested-couple-released-without-charge)).  Later, police said that statement had been the result of "poor communication" ([The Guardian, 24 Dec.](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/dec/24/suggestion-that-drone-did-not-exist-down-to-poor-communications)).

Regardless, I haven't found any photos or videos of the drones.  Are there any?  If not, why not?  Were they too small (or far away) to be seen by a cellphone camera?  But then how could humans see them?  How can 67 people see a drone in this day and age and none of them record it?  Is it plausible that there actually were no drones?

Comment: There’s a picture here: https://www.dailystar.co.uk/news/latest-news/749188/breaking-gatwick-airport-drone-picture-easyjet-delays-flights-cancel-compensation-travel/amp but the twitter account it was originally posted on seems to be down, so not sure how valid it is. But it’s definitely difficult to take a picture of a small moving drone from a distance.

Comment: An “unverified” video (difficult to say this was even at Gatwick): https://news.sky.com/video/gatwick-drone-caught-on-camera-in-unverified-footage-11587927

Comment: On meta: [Is the 'Gatwick drones' question on-topic?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3767/14897)

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that there were no drones, and this was a case of mass hysteria.

One actual crashed drone was discovered during the search, but that could very likely have been a hobbyist drone that got away, days, perhaps weeks earlier.  Lost toy drones happen all the time (even though it *shouldn't* happen near a major airport, it does...)

https://www.secretflying.com/posts/police-admit-it-is-a-possibility-there-was-never-a-drone-at-gatwick-airport/

Comment: -1 You need a better source than a discredited police report

Comment: Police think otherwise, perhaps this newer article from Feb 2019 can help: https://www.nytimes.com/reuters/2019/02/21/technology/21reuters-britain-gatwick-drone.html

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia page on the event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatwick_Airport_drone_incident#Investigation) says:

> No videos or photographs of the drone were handed to the police.

The [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/12/24/world/europe/gatwick-airport-drone.html) also says there is no solid evidence.

Despite multiple eye witness accounts, no photos or videos of a drone exist.

Comment: Police think otherwise, perhaps this newer article from Feb 2019 can help: https://www.nytimes.com/reuters/2019/02/21/technology/21reuters-britain-gatwick-drone.html

Comment: The question is: ***Are there any photos or videos of the drones at Gatwick?***.  The answer is clearly, *"No, there are not"* (regardless of what the cops might believe).

Comment: Note that the article says, *"The operator also knew to fly the drone past air traffic control, where a ban on mobile phones would keep people from filming it."* So if the ATC saw it, plus the other eyewitnesses, it *is* evidence, even if not concrete (subjective).

Comment: OOI why did you post another answer rather than just update your previous one?

Comment: Here's an [archived copy of the 2019-02-21 Reuters article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190228180313/https://www.reuters.com/article/us-britain-gatwick-drone/police-think-gatwick-worker-may-have-launched-drone-attack-times-says-idUSKCN1QA16E).  The ban on mobile phones at ATC is interesting as it explains one reason *why* there are no photos or videos.